# jQuery, как вернуть json из $.post() в функцию

Tags: javascript

Напишите пожалуйста человеческим языков как получить json ответ из $.post() ?

```js
function products(){
  var json = $.post('url', function(data){
    // в переменной "data" json ответ
  });
  return json;
}
console.log(products()) // возвращает object
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Пробовал через `.done(function() { })` , не помогло.

Есть похожие ответы, пишут что это делается как то асинхронно, но только вот как, не могу додуматься, нужно вернуть целиком то что в переменной `data`

Желательно пример, чтобы по нему было понятно почему так.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: у вас же прям в коде написано, где json ответ находится :D

Answer (score 0):

С `.done()` ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
function products(){
  var json = $.post('url')
  return json;
}
products().done(function(data){
  console.log(data)
});
```

Более эстетично будет так:

```
let products=()=>$.post('url')
products().done(data=>{
  console.log(data)
})
```